# AngularJS refactoring form into components/directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a large form with many subsections that I'd like to refactor into individual `components`. I could just use `ng-include`, but I've read that `components` are preferred. However, `components` use isolated scopes, and I could pass in the entire form as an attribute, but that seems like it'd be introducing too many unnecessary watchers. What's the best way to refactor something like this?

Comment: I'd recommend to create directives for each re-usable part of code.

Comment: You can just google it.  Check these posts, you will get the idea. [1. Form based directives](http://www.sitepoint.com/form-based-directives-angularjs/)    [2. Angular component](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/thinking-in-components-angular-js/)